# Different view controller display at start app

Tags: swift, startapp

I try to explain situation:
I have two view controllers: viewHome and viewStartTest.
When student start app first time, don't have any data about his test in table.
In this situation should be display viewStartTest controller after launch screen.
But when he start app again and condition "test is finished" is true, viewHome controller should be display at start.
I try to put this code in AppDelegate.swift and simulate finished test but still not working, thanks for help:

```
// 0 - false, 1 - True
var conditionTest = 1

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if conditionTest == 1 {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewStartTest: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewStartTest")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewStartTest
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ViewHome: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewHome")
        self.window?.rootViewController = ViewHome
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Correct Scene delegate code after discussion below:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
          if conditionTest == 1 {


        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewStartTest: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewStartTest")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewStartTest
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {


        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ViewHome: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewHome")
        self.window?.rootViewController = ViewHome
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
```

Comment: Put this code in your scene delegate. Then it works. And use window in scene delegate.

Comment: Hi I try it but with black screen after launch screen...

Comment: Can you share scene delegate. And check identifier of your viewcontroller

Comment: @Kasim I added it into question

Comment: You can use => var window: UIWindow? so remove self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

Comment: Super @Kasim it working now! Big thanks :)

Comment: Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of `conditionTest` somewhere. I would suggest using `UserDefaults` . This is an example of how you could implement it:

**NavigationController:**

```
class MainNavigationControllerViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if isLoggedIn() {
        let homeController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
        viewControllers = [homeController]
    }
}

fileprivate func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.isLoggedIn()
}
}
```

**Extension for UserDefaults:**

```
extension UserDefaults {

func setIsLoggedIn(value: Bool) {
    set(value, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    synchronize()
}

func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")    }
}
```

**How to use:**

with the above code you can simply login/logout the user. Make sure to call `.synchronize()`

*Login:*

```
UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

*Logout:*

```
UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: false)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```